# VBA code to cut and a paste a slide

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I am writing a VBA code in Excel 2010 to search for a particular text (
that I am inputting from Excel) in a Presentation, cut that slide and paste the slide next to slide where the same text (again inputting from Excel) is found in the Presentation.

And I want to repeat the same for around 50 times, i.e, I want to find 50 texts in PPT and cut those slides and paste them somewhere else.

Can I do this using Excel VBA code??

Comment: You'll need to add a reference library (for me it's `Tools > References... > Microsoft PowerPoint 15.0 Object Library`). You'll then need to look up a code to save a slide as picture then a code to paste that picture in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
You'll need to add PowerPoint's Object Library and look up the existing solutions with Google.